# How do I find the corresponding annotation / Java based configuration counterpart for some XML configuration snippet?

Tags: java, spring

I use annotation-based or Java-based configuration to set up my Spring applications. I usually don't have any XML configuration files anywhere.

Some examples in the documentation only show XML snippets to demonstrate how something can be done. For example, if I want to make all methods with name "get*" to rollback when checked exception NoProductInStockException gets thrown, I can https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
    <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" rollback-for="NoProductInStockException"/>
    <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

There is no advice on how to do the same with annotations or Java-based configuration. I would prefer to configure everything the same way, and not mix in some XML configuration to just change this one thing.

Usually I google around and fiddle with different stackoverflow suggestions eyes half closed until one of them works.

Is there always a annotation-based or Java configuration based counterpart for the XML configuration snippets? Are there some clear steps for how to reproduce identical configuration with annotations or Java based configuration?

Comment: Have you read [Specifying Transaction Settings](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#tx-prog-template-settings) section from the same reference?

Comment: No, but now that I did, it's not clear to me how to use that to achieve the same system wide rollback behavior?

Comment: That section starts with a specific service "SimpleService" which has a TransactionTemplate variable. I do not use any TransactionTemplates yet, and want to specify rollback for all services, not a specific one.